# Eclipse doesn't want to run simple JavaFX application

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have other classes named Test in other packages and one class with the same name in the default package.

When I click the Run button in Eclipse, instead of running this class, it runs another Test class from inside another package instead:

```
package jfx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Circle circ = new Circle(40, 40, 30);
        Group root = new Group(circ);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);

        stage.setTitle("My JavaFX Application");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could be related to your launch configuration.  Can you verify that you do not try to launch the class Test from a different package?

Comment: When I hover the cursor over the Run button, a tooltip appears that says 'Run Test(1)'. I checked the run configuration, and Test(1) indeed points to another class. A class called Test in package test. That has the same code inside...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `main` method to allow Eclipse recognize the program as runnable application

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Note that this is really an Eclipse problem: as of Java 8, the JVM can start up from an `Application` subclass even if it has no `main(...)` method. However, Eclipse doesn't recognize this.

Comment: To my surprise, this fixed the problem. I'm surprised because I had another class with the same code inside, in another package - and no main method - and Eclipse launched it just fine. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure? or is it an old runnable `Test` class in your classpath. Try cleaning the project to verify...

Comment: I cleaned the project, and commented out the main() method from both classes. Only the one in the jfx package would launch. I deleted the Test class in the test package, and jfx.Test could still run. I got totally confused, so I ended up deleting both Test classes, along with their run configurations, then creating a new Test class in a new package. And indeed, without the main() method, Eclipse can't find the class, or run it. So it looks as if you need that extra code for Eclipse to launch the JavaFX application correctly. Thanks for your help!